# How to Convert form-data type API request body to JSON format in C#

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-core, .net-core

I need to store the API request and response body of my application but the issue is request with the form-data type is getting stored in some different format

I just tried by this code which removes some numbers and lines from the body:

```
var requestTime = DateTime.Now;
var requestBodyContent = await ReadRequestBody(request);
int bcode = requestBodyContent.IndexOf("Content-Disposition:");
if (bcode > 0)
{
    string jung1 = requestBodyContent.Substring(0, bcode - 1);
    requestBodyContent = requestBodyContent.Replace(jung1, "");
}
context.Items["Guid"] = GUID;

requestBodyContent = requestBodyContent.Replace("Content-Disposition: form-data; name=", "");
```

Its giving response like

> "UserId"
> 2
> "DeviceId"
> 126
> "VentorId"
> 23
> "UserName"

I need to get the request body as a JSON format to store in my database
The use of request body is some times I need to resend the api request with same data of previous request
How to convert this to JSON format or is there any way to directly convert form-data to JSON?

Comment: AFAIK, you can apply the `[FromForm]` attribute to your controller action. `public IActionResult YourAction([FromFrom] YourRequestModel request) { ... }`. You don't have to do such complex logic for manual deserialization.

Comment: Actually Its FromFrom but I need to store the data Json in my db

Comment: As you apply `[FromForm]`, you can straight serialize the `request`.

Comment: @ShakeebKp your question is unclear. There's no JSON in your request. If you want a JSON string, you'll have to create it. Storing JSON in databases is *very* unusual because you can't query it or combine it with anything else or use indexes to speed up queries. If you want to dump a JSON representation of the request somewhere for eg logging or auditing purposes, just serialize the object

Answer (score 1):

Apply the [`[FromForm]`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.mvc.fromformattribute?view=aspnetcore-8.0) attribute to your action parameter.

> Specifies that a parameter or property should be bound using form-data in the request body.

And using the JSON library such as *System.Text.Json*/*Newtonsoft.Json* for serialization.

```cs
using System.Text.Json;

public IActionResult YourControllerAction([FromForm] YourRequestModel request)
{
   ...

   string serializedRequestContent = JsonSerializer.Serialize(request);

   ...
}
```

Reference: [Model Binding](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/models/model-binding?view=aspnetcore-8.0#sources)